# OpenSSL Error while generating private key

Tags: openssl, key, rsa

I'm using a command `genrsa -des3 -out key.key 4096`, which someone recommeded me in my prev questions. 
But I am getting error. I don't know why

```
2284:error:0906906F:PEM routines:PEM_ASN1_write_bio:read key:.\crypto\pem\pem_li
b.c:334:
error in genrsa
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be multiple reasons.

Check these:

```
Make sure that catalog is writable
Make sure that you provided two times same key(no typos)
```

Comment: Yes, the directory was read-only.